# Jetty Pi4J I2C error oppening /dev/i2c-1

Tags: java, arduino, jetty, raspberry-pi, i2c

I'm trying to send data from Raspberry PI to Arduino via I2c.
When i execute the code with a stand alone java application i'm able to send and receive data with NO problem (the code bellow is giving me the expected result).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // get I2C bus instance
    final I2CBus bus = I2CFactory.getInstance(I2CBus.BUS_1);
    I2CDevice arduino = bus.getDevice(0x04);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
    buffer[0] = 1;
    arduino.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

    Thread.sleep(100);
    buffer[0] = 0;
    int number = arduino.read(buffer, 0, 1);
}
```

Then i try the same code, but this time it is inside a Servlet, using Jetty in the Raspberry Pi, and i get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot open file handle for /dev/i2c-1 got -1 back.
    at com.pi4j.io.i2c.impl.I2CBusImpl.<init>(I2CBusImpl.java:96)
    at com.pi4j.io.i2c.impl.I2CBusImpl.getBus(I2CBusImpl.java:70)
    at com.pi4j.io.i2c.I2CFactory.getInstance(I2CFactory.java:56)..
```

Does anyone know what may be happening?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that in one case your process has sudo rights and it doesn't in the other case?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
I2CFactory.getInstance(I2CBus.BUS_0);
```

in some cases, the BUS is inverted so try this, i hope it helps :)

Comment: There. I made an answer out of it. If you don't think it is an answer, then it is a comment, so delete it.

Comment: Please add some explanation.